# passing an uninitialized variable throwing an error using C

Tags: c, memory-management, data-structures, tree

I have this code :

```
        typedef struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node *left;
        struct node *right;
} node;

void Build (node *root , int i)
{
        if (i < 7)
    {
        root = (node *)malloc (sizeof(node));
        root->data = i;
        Build(root->left,2*i+1);
        Build(root->right,2*i+2);
    }
    else
        root = NULL;
}
void Print (node *root)
{
    if (root)
    {
        printf ("%d  ",root->data);
        Print(root->left);
        Print(root->right);
    }
}
void main()
{
    node *tree;

    Build(tree,0);
    Print(tree);
}
```

two things that I dont understand , 
1. why can't I pass Build(tree,0) ? it says it's uninitialized , but why shuold I care if it's uninitialized ? I'm allocating all the memory needed straight away so it's gonna be pointing on the new allocated node.

how can I fix this code? thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `node *` to tree is uninitialized.

```
node *tree;
```

That matters because the code line

```
root = (node *)malloc (sizeof(node));
```

allocates memory to a **local copy** of *root*.  Once you leave function scope of *Build*, the copy of *root* goes out of scope.  Memory leak.

Remember, everything is passed by value in C.

If you really want *Build* to allocate the memory, the signature would have to be

```
void Build (node **root , int i)
```

and your code in that method would have to refer to `*root` instead of `root`.

Comment: but even if it's local - so what? it should not dissapear when I finish the func

Comment: Sure it does.  The pointer is passed by value, which means there is a local copy of the pointer on the stack... a pointer that points to nothing.  Your malloc assigns memory to the local (stack) copy of root.  Try stepping through in a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Parameters are passed by value - the location in memory is not actually passed.  So when you call Build, you're just passing in the value of tree, which happens to be uninitialized.  The Build function creates a local root variable with that value - when you set `root = ...` in Build, you're over-writing that undefined value with the new value, but that new value is still just in the local root variable - it is never seen by the tree variable in main.

What you really want to do is have Build return the newly created tree pointer:

```
node * Build(int i)
{
    node *root;
    ...
        root->left = Build(2*i+1)
    ...
    return root;
}

void main() 
{
    ...
    tree = Build(0);
    ...
}
```